# convert string into date

Tags: php, date

Hi I know this question is a bit trivial. I googled it but could not find the exact problem anywhere.

I have a string which contains a application filling date how can I convert this string into date

```
 $appln_filling_date = '20020315';
```

The type of appln_filling_date is string I want to convert its type to date and want the data remain the same. The field in the database has a type date.

**EDIT**

This is what I am trying to do

```
 $appln_filling_date = strtotime($appln_data['bibliographic-data']['application-reference']['document-id']['1']['date']['$']);
 $appln_filling_date = date('Y-m-d', $appln_filling_date);
```

Comment: If it's a string, where are the quotes?

Comment: oh come on imagine the quotes :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your date is in some [standard date format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) use this example:

```
$d = new DateTime('20020315');
echo $d->format('Y-m-d');

# or [if you do not have DateTime, which is in php >= 5.2.0]

$t = strtotime('20020315');
echo date('Y-m-d', $t);
```

If your date is not in some standard format use this example:

```
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat('d . Y - m', '15 . 2002 - 03');
echo $d->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: I get 2002-03-15 and I look at the type of the variable by using gettype() method it still returns string

Comment: What type would you like to be returned?

Comment: i want it return date type because the field in which i will insert this in database has date as type

Comment: PHP does not have date type. Just insert this into database, it will work. Please read > http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.php

Comment: it is giving me this error Call to a member function format() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\idp\vendor\doctrine-dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Types\DateType.php

Comment: What is datetime parameter? can you var_dump it?

Comment: didn't get your question what do you mean by datetime parameter?

Comment: `$d = new DateTime($X);` what is `$X` ? can you `var_dump($X)` and show me the output ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', $appln_filling_date);
```

Comment: @UmairIqbal What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: @UmairIqbal That's weird. You can investigate this issue or go with Glavić's answer.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me like a charm

```
 $appln_filling_date = $appln_data['bibliographic-data']['application-reference']['document-id']['1']['date']['$'];
 $appln_filling_date = date_create(date('Y-m-d', $appln_filling_date));
```

Thanks for the down voting

Comment: You know that `date_create()` is alias for ` DateTime::__construct()` ? It is the same thing. http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-create.php

Comment: @Glavić I use the above code to insert date into my database and the date is stored as "1970-08-20" but in my view when i show it , the date comes like "1970-08-20 00:00:00" how can i remove the time ? the code in view is {{ patent.applnFilingDate.date }}

Comment: Done using {{ patent.applnFilingDate.date | date('Y-m-d') }}

Comment: If you only need to store date, then use DATE field in db table, and not DATETIME. I don't know what is this syntax that you are showing...

Comment: thnx for the reply i did it :)